# How to send values selected in ListBox to java webservice parameter in BIRT?

Tags: web-services, birt, birt-deapi

I have a **java webservice** which takes values of Locations and performs action.
In my **BIRT** report, I have a **ListBox** which contains names of all the locations.
When tried to link values from **ListBox** to **webservice parameter**, BIRT developer give warning message as :

> If a user selects multiple values from report parameter, the data set
>   parameter uses only the first value

.

I tried creating a hidden report parameter `[RP_Hidden_Locations]` in BIRT which is of string type and copied values from ListBox report parameter `[RP_All_Locations]` as `[RP_Hidden_Locations].value =  params["RP_All_Locations"].value.join("','");`

This didn't work and null values were received in webservice method.

Please help!

PS:
Data source for Data Set in BIRT is Webserivce Data Source
and sending report parameter values as shown below

```
<locations>?&RP_Hidden_Locations&?</locations>
```

Answer (score 0):

First Create the hidden variable.
In the script tab of the dataset, select before open.Here join all the values sent by the listbox report parameter. Use this:

params[RP_Hidden_Locations]=  "'"+params["RP_All_Locations"].value.join("','")+"'";

Now set the SOAP Request to send this hidden parameter.